# Edting a URL to display nothing after the TLD

Tags: php, html

The variable `$rowad["1site"]` is a URL.  How could I keep the entire URL in the hyperlink, but have the anchor text be an edited version of the URL, showing nothing after the TLD?

```
echo '<td style="" class="pointlink"><span class="pointlink"><a href="http://'.$rowad["1site"].'">'.$rowad["1site"].'</a></td>';
```

Comment: I know you got your solution from a similar question you posted  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253953/limiting-a-variable-to-display-only-50-characters) But is there any chance you could give feedback on this question to help other in future. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can explode the URL, something like:

```
$newUrl = explode('/', $rowad['1site']);
```

Then add `$newUrl[0]` where you want.