# Limiting a variable to display only 50 characters

Tags: php, html

How can I limit the anchor text below to show only 50 characters?

```
echo '<td style="" class="pointlink"><span class="pointlink"><a href="http://'.$rowad["1site"].'">'.$rowad["1site"].'</a></td>';
```

Comment: substr() is the function you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substr` function, like

`echo '<td style="" class="pointlink"><span class="pointlink"><a href="http://'.$rowad["1site"].'">'.substr($rowad["1site"],0,50).'</a></td>';`

Answer (score 7):

[`substr`](http://php.net/substr)

Alternatively, you could use CSS:

```
.pointlink {
    width: 150px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Adjust the width as needed, and an ellipsis will be automatically be used to cut off the text.

Comment: Upvoting - because you would have ellipsis to show truncation and this can be dynamically resized based on the size of the page.

Comment: cute, but inefficient and with serous browser support issues.

Comment: Supported by all major browsers: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

Comment: here is a better one by version - IE6 supported it - how high are your standards? http://caniuse.com/text-overflow

Comment: well if w3schools, says so it must be true :-) but my phone browser does not support it :(

Comment: Really? what kind of phone - android/iphone are based on webkit which should have no problem doing it.

Comment: you are, right, i apologise, i did launch a test on the phone, but failed to interpret the results correctly. - But um you do save some user and server bandwidth trimming at the server, rather than letting the browser do it (could be an issues if its a large amount of text)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function to cut the text down to 50 characters

```
function cut_text( $text, $len ) {
    return strlen( $text ) > $len ?
        substr( $text, 0, $len ) + '...' :
        $text;
}
echo '<td style="" class="pointlink"><span class="pointlink"><a href="http://'.$rowad["1site"].'">' . cut_text( $rowad["1site"], 50 ) . '</a></td>';
```

Comment: Nice - but you should use '&hellip;' to get a real one '…' instead of '...' - the point is to save space after all :-)   (LOL - that looks a lot bigger in the edit box...)